# Is there a Script/Code to import data into Drupal 8, from external MySQL?

Tags: drupal, migration, drupal-8

So here is my requirement:

I have an existing application that uses MySQL, and has around 200 odd tables. I want to move to Drupal 8 and need to import this data, in some content types. Basically, I want to migrate data and create nodes. I want to write an standalone script, that would read from MySQL, bootstrap Drupal 8 and create nodes. Any suggestions, examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 8 has the Migrate API built into core so you would want to use that. Here's a good primer article, although it's a year old so you want to check out any advancements/new stuff you may want to use first:

https://www.sitepoint.com/your-first-drupal-8-migration/

Here's the Migrate API docs:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-api-overview

...and here's the Migrate Plus module which has some example code:

https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus

You want to take some time to model your new application with Drupal 8 - 200 tables sounds like something you don't want to necessarily re-implement. Build out your new structure then use the various tools in the Migrate suite to import the data into your new entities & content types.